# Ios 7 custom UINavigationController animation fails with mapView in destination controller

Tags: ios, animation, ios7, uiviewcontroller, custom-transition

I am playing around with the new `UIViewControllerContextTransitioning` between `UViewController`inside `UINavigationViewController`

And what I have and what I want to achieve is quite simple but I fail somewhere

I have a `MKMapView` (300px * 60px) inside a `UIScrollView`. And from a click on that map (no matter where in the visible scroll it is) I want to segue over to next view that containts a fullsized `MKMapView`.
The feeling and animation I am aiming for is for the user to feel they are being sucked into the map (kind of) =)

I have so far added: 
`<UIViewControllerTransitioningDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate>`

and

```
-(id<UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning>)navigationController:(UINavigationController *)navigationController animationControllerForOperation:(UINavigationControllerOperation)operation fromViewController:(UIViewController *)fromVC toViewController:(UIViewController *)toVC{

if (operation == UINavigationControllerOperationPush) {
    NSLog(@"inside itself");
    FixRTransitionAnimator *animator = [FixRTransitionAnimator new];
    animator.presenting = YES;
    CGRect absoluteframe = [self.mainScrollView convertRect:self.mapView.frame toView:self.view];
    animator.mapFrame = absoluteframe;
    NSLog(@"the map frame is %@", NSStringFromCGRect(self.mapView.frame));
    return animator;
}
else
    NSLog(@"nope its outside");
return nil;
}
```

And to the `prepareForSegue` method I have:

```
   [super prepareForSegue:sender sender:sender];

    MapViewController *mapViewController = segue.destinationViewController;
    mapViewController.transitioningDelegate = self;
    mapViewController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationCustom;
```

And finally I have the `FixRTransitionAnimator.m``

```
-(NSTimeInterval)transitionDuration:(id<UIViewControllerContextTransitioning>)transitionContext{
NSLog(@"the time is timed");
return 0.5f;
}
 -(void)animateTransition:(id<UIViewControllerContextTransitioning>)transitionContext{
NSLog(@"we are inside %@",NSStringFromCGRect(self.mapFrame));
UIViewController *fromVController = [transitionContext viewControllerForKey:UITransitionContextFromViewControllerKey];
UIViewController *toVController = [transitionContext viewControllerForKey:UITransitionContextToViewControllerKey];

CGRect endFrame = CGRectMake(0, 0, [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width,[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height);

if (self.presenting) {
    fromVController.view.userInteractionEnabled = NO;

    [[transitionContext containerView]addSubview:fromVController.view];
    [[transitionContext containerView]addSubview:toVController.view];

    toVController.view.frame = self.mapFrame;


     [UIView animateWithDuration:[self transitionDuration:transitionContext]      animations:^{
        fromVController.view.tintAdjustmentMode = UIViewTintAdjustmentModeDimmed;
        NSLog(@"inside the animation");
        toVController.view.frame = endFrame;
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        [transitionContext completeTransition:YES];
    }];
}else{
   ...
}

}
```

The transition animation works nice and fine with the destinationViewController empty. But with the map inside the animation works really weird and not at all as I wanted.

Any1 got any pointers to what I miss or need to think of?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I wrote a post in another [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22884111/how-to-use-uiviewcontrolleranimatedtransitioning-with-uinavigationcontroller/25026102#25026102), but make sure you are setting your UINavigationControllerDelegate.

There is a `UIViewControllerTransitioningDelegate` for *presented* controllers, and a `UINavigationControllerDelegate` for *pushed* controllers.  The delegate methods inside the protocols return your animator.

Comment: Yes this was it m8. Have understood the API a bit more since I posted the q =) tnx though!